# tlmgr cannot setup TLPDB

Tags: errors, texlive, ubuntu

I'm trying to update my installation of texlive 2013 under Ubuntu 13.10.
However, I followed the instruction on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/7561), but I get an error

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
> cannot setup TLPDB in /home/USER/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.

I tried searching for this error but it got me nowhere. I'm used to work with MikTex on Windows, but now I'm migrating to Ubuntu and get no idea what went wrong. Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: It seems you have created symbolic links in `/usr/bin`, which I don't recommend. It's much better to add the path to the TeX Live binaries to the `PATH` environment variable. It's possible that you have also the Debian provided TeX Live and, if some package has been installed later than the vanilla TeX Live, `tlmgr` gets confused.

Comment: I haven't done anything. It is an installation using the `apt-get`. What are the drawbacks of having the symlink instead of the variables?

Comment: The installation with `apt-get` doesn't provide `tlmgr`; and the instruction you refer to *don't* use `apt-get`.

Comment: Personally I avoid `apt-get` for `texlive` and use [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: @egreg I don't know what I did then. So I end up with a `tlmgr` by installing it later on? I'm quite lost here. So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If your TeX Live has been installed with `apt-get` you can't install `tlmgr` over it. And, if you do in some way, you can't rely on it to work.

Comment: @egreg `tlmgr` is included in package `texlive-base` in Ubuntu 13.10, preset to run in [user mode](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE). The first line in the documentation is a warning that one should expect breakage.

Comment: @adn I just tried on virtual box with 13.10 and I can reproduce your problem. It's strange that others have not experienced this (google results are few). One option is to uninstall the Ubuntu packages and use [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu). It has been tested on 13.10.

Comment: @scottkosty, I found this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1242914 but it seems that they say it is not a bug, and is just configuration issues or is just broken yet. I did what suggested, and reinstalled.

Comment: Read the `User Mode` section in the [tlmgr documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE), and you will realize that `--gui` is not yet supported. Anyway, I can reproduce your problem; it seems `tlmgr` is not yet usable at all, although I felt so excited about it.

Comment: I especially love being yelled at to read documentation for soemthing that isn't there.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Sorry to reactivate this old post but there was no correct answer.

The message :

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!) cannot setup TLPDB in /home/USER/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.

is generated when `tlmgr` was not initialized. In most cases, launching the following command (as a normal user) solves the problem :

```
 $ tlmgr init-usertree
```

This command will create few folders inside your home directory. See [the man page](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE) for explanation :

> Before using tlmgr in user mode, you have to set up the user tree with the init-usertree action. This creates usertree/web2c and usertree/tlpkg/tlpobj, and a minimal usertree/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb. At that point, you can tell tlmgr to do the (supported) actions by adding the --usermode command line option.

Comment: Running this command still gives `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!) cannot setup TLPDB in /home/adin/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.`

Comment: Indeed! I just checked bugs reports and your problem is related to a bug in ubuntu 13.10 package. See post #3 and #4 in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1242914). You have to wait the update (probably with the next version of ubuntu) or to install manually texlive (without using ubuntu package). On my debian unstable, the bug is fixed and `tlmgr` works fine.

Comment: To me it just changed errors, now I get: "tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec"

Comment: @LucasSoares You might want to install `xzdec` package. See Taciano answer or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180230/kubuntu-texlive-manually-installed-tlmgr-not-working#180231

Comment: @ppr I will do that, thanks. Out of curiosity, what does the ```xzdec``` package do?

Comment: @LucasSoares It is a decompression tool. It allows you decompress the binary you want to install.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? I get `(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TeX Live 2013 is frozen forever and will no
longer be updated.  This happens in preparation for a new release.

`

Comment: When I run the command I get `Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/me/texmf!`

Answer (score 133):

In my texlive installation (in ubuntu 15.04), I tried installing framed.sty latex package with the following command:

```
$ tlmgr install framed
```

I got this error message:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/myusername/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5435.
```

I took the following steps:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir texmf
$ tlmgr init-usertree
```

I tried to install the framed.sty latex package again with the command:

```
$ tlmgr install framed
```

I got this error message:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

So, I installed xzdec and I tried to install the package again:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xzdec
$ tlmgr install framed
```

It worked!

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: package repository http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] install: framed [8k]
tlmgr: package log updated: /home/myusername/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
```

Comment: Installing "xzdec" worked for me, as well!

Comment: still the only working solution in 18.04

Comment: working great for me.

Comment: I already get "Cannot determine type of tlpdb from..." when I run `tlmgr init-usertree`.

Answer (score 8):

The version installed by the command:

```
$sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base
```

is outdated. I had to download the most up-to-date version from:
http://ftp.leg.uct.ac.za/pub/packages/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/

It included most of the current packages. To install it you have to remove the old versions of tex-live you may have:

```
   sudo rm -rf /usr/local/texlive/*
   sudo rm -rf ~/.texlive*
```

Some more info about quick installation can be gleaned from:
http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue and fixed it thus:

```
sudo apt-get install xzdec
tlmgr update --self
tlmgr install etoolbox titling
```

I was getting the error

```
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/tama/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
```

when trying to run:

```
sudo tlmgr update --all
```

So I tried to update tlmgr, thinking it an issue with ubuntu's packaged version of tlmgr.

```
~$ tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

So it turns out to be two errors; (1) Ubuntu packages tlmgr but not its dependent program, xzdec, and (2) tlmgr outputs the wrong error message; it should have said "unable to find xzdec" but instead said something general and vague about TLPDB.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  This seems to be restricted to an update of some packages only, not complete TLPDB

Comment: This seemed to help at the beginning , but when trying to do anything when tlmgr I get:  Unknown directive ...containerchecksum 06c8c1fff8b025f6f55f8629af6e41a6dd695e13bbdfe8b78b678e9cb0cfa509826355f4ece20d8a99b49bcee3c5931b8d766f0fc3dae0d6a645303d487600b0... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5761.

Answer (score 5):

I **reinstalled** the [**`TeX Live`**](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) by using [**`install-tl-ubuntu`**](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) and it worked.

> However, it is a rigorous solution for the given issue. So, I would
>   only suggest you to perform this after you've tried rest of the
>   answers here.

Answer (score 3):

For me (on Ubuntu 13.10 with TeX Live 2013) I solved the problem by re-installing the `texlive-base` package.

```
# sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base
```

I installed my tex-dist with the normal installer, not the `install-tl-ubuntu`.

Comment: Unfortunately for me reinstalling `texlive-base` didn't help

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this by rearranging the PATH command in .bashrc.  The problem manifested itself when the path was set like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux
```

However, changing to this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

fixed the problem.  I do not have TeXLive installed under the Ubuntu Software Centre, I installed it manually from `install-tl`.

Comment: It is not a good idea to add the PATH to the `.bashrc`, then several editors will not be able to find LaTeX if the editor is started via a menu. Better to add it to `.profile` and log out and in again (that file is only read once per session AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks @daleif.  I found setting the path confusing under Ubuntu... for example, it is unclear to me from this [post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) exactly where the path should be updated to be seen by the most applications. Editing `.bashrc` seemed to be the most appropriate.

Comment: Discovered that though TexLive is not installed according to the software centre, it is part of the base install of Ubuntu 13.10 and I removed it with apt-get.  Now the order in $PATH does not matter.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I get this: (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I got the same thing which seemed to have been fixed by `sudo apt-get install xzdec`.

Answer (score 0):

I got here after

```
tlmgr install luainputenc
```

didn't work for me.

To conclude, what worked for me was:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall texlive-base
tlmgr init-usertree

tlmgr install luainputenc
```

So thanks, everyone! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is rather a summary of some of the answers here