# Error using tlmgr in Tex Live

Tags: texlive

I am getting an error when using tlmgr to update or install latex packages. For example, the command `tlmgr update -all` in the terminal yields the following response:

> (running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
>
> cannot setup TLPDB in home/USER/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5308.

Comment: `tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`?

Comment: I guess you installed TL through Debian's package manager? In this case, you can't update the installation itself using tlmgr as that would conflict with the package manager. So it is trying to switch to 'user mode' which would install updates in your personal texmf tree. For some reason, that is failing. Are you running this as yourself? You should be i.e. don't use root or sudo since you can't update the installed stuff anyway. Do you have write permission to /home/USER (USER should be your username)? What does ls -l /home/USER/texmf give?

Comment: @Werner, running that command once again gave the same response as above.

I installed TL according to this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017055/get-started-with-latex-on-linux. Yes, I am using a regular user mode, not root or sudo. When I tried "ls -l /home/USER/texmf," it gave "ls: cannot access /home/USER/texmf: No such file or directory"

Comment: I tried doing: sudo `which tlmgr` update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed. However, it gave the same message as above (cannot setup TLPDB).

Comment: Same question here without answer - http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137428/tlmgr-cannot-setup-tlpdb.

Answer (score 2):

you should, either install the Debian packages of texlive, or the install TeXLive using its own installer; details are in

https://wiki.debian.org/Latex

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu provides for an automated way to install a seemingly working version of texlive.

As some users have noticed, there seems to be a bug with tlmgr when using the default version from Ubuntu repositories. This can be avoided by using this approach while still allowing for the use of debian's `apt-get` for further package installation.

I got the idea from http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=23749