# tikz-cd new syntax

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I've been using `tikz-cd` for years now, and I find it incredibly easy to make commutative diagrams with it.

Recently, I saw [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) document which describes a new and simpler syntax. I tried making a diagram using that syntax, that is, putting everything inside `[]` for the arrows instead of using multiple `{}`, and I got multiple errors.

Here are some examples:

This is how I would normally do a diagram:

```
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow{r}{f} & B \arrow{r}{g} & C \arrow{r} & 0
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
```

This is how I would do a diagram with the new syntax:

```
    \[
    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r, "f"] & B \arrow[r, "g"] & C \arrow[r] & 0
    \end{tikzcd}
    \]
```

This second example compiles but I get lots of errors, some are even related to the package `xcolor` which I'm not even using. Also it does not show the labels on the arrows.

Does someone know what is the problem? Am I doing something wrong? Do I need a newer version of TeX Live? (I'm using TeX Live 2014 on Ubuntu 14.10).

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What versions of `pgf` and `tikz-cd` do you have? (run `tlmgr info pgf` and `tlmgr info tikz-cd` from a terminal)

Comment: It returns this error:
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/username/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5435.

Comment: I think the problem is actually the ubuntu package of texlive

Comment: Well, at least it seems that the problems with tlmgr are well documented: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152922/error-using-tlmgr-in-tex-live

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm sticking to the old syntax for now. Should I delete the question?

Comment: I think it is worth to leave it open, maybe someone that has experienced the same problems can shed some light :-)

Comment: For what it's worth, you probably need to update `pgf`/TikZ. I would guess,  the new syntax uses features of the `quotes` library that is new in TikZ 3, and that you still have 2.10. (Oh, you are using `xcolor` by the way, TikZ loads it.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it works well with an up-to-date distribution (and even with an older one, but not so old as 2014).