# (k)ubuntu, TeXLive manually installed, tlmgr not working

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

(Summary: `tmlgr` was not working in a typical manual (non-apt) install of TeXLive in Ubuntu.)

In Kubuntu, I used `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, and `install-tl --gui=text` to make a basic install. That is, I prefer not to use the full install, and get the few packages I need as I need them (`parskip`, etc.).

I put

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH
```

in my `~/.profile` (and reboot) so that my Linux can find `latex` and `tlmgr`.

Here are the type of errors I get when trying to use `tlmgr`.

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)                                          
cannot setup TLPDB in /root/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
```

Googling for this leads to a suggestion to use

```
tlmgr init-usertree
```

Then I get

```
sudo tlmgr install parskip.sty
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

Okay, drum roll for the answer... as simply formulating the question carefully pointed me to an obvious next step, which seems to be the "terminal" of my problem.

Comment: My solution now may be to side-step this Ubuntu/ TeX Live mess and keep a `texmf` directory backedup with the additional packages I need, downloaded manually from CTAN.

Answer (score 52):

So, what doesn't work is

```
tlmgr install xzdec
```

Why would it? `tlmgr` is not working yet. So, as I'm writing the question, I realize I might try

```
sudo apt-get install xzdec
```

and it worked! What `.tex` document would once not compile, now does!

(Well anyways, I next tried `sudo tlmgr install parskip`, and then the TeX document compiled, but I'm hoping that on-the-fly package installing is now working.)